# Thumbnails are not automatically generated. Nothing is created even in the thumbnail folder. What should I do?

Tags: php

Thumbnails are not automatically generated. Nothing is created even in the thumbnail folder. What should I do?
The code used is this.

```
public function call_upload()
        {
            $config['upload_path']  = './product_img';
            $config['allowed_types']    = 'gif|jpg|png'; 
            $config['overwrite']    = TRUE;
            $config['max_size'] = 10000000;
            $config['max_width']    = 10000;
            $config['max_height']   = 10000;
            $this->upload->initialize($config); 

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('pic13')) 
                $picname="";
            else
            {
                $picname=$this->upload->data("file_name");

                $config['image_library']    = 'gd2';
                $config['source_image'] = './product_img'.$picname;
                $config['thumb_marker'] = '';
                $config['new_image']    = './product_img/thumb';
                $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
                $config['maintain_ratio']   = TRUE;
                $config['width']    = 200;
                $config['height']   = 150;

                $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

                $this->image_lib->resize();
            }
            return $picname;
        }
```

Comment: What is `$this`? Are you using a framework? Is it a custom object you've implemented?

Answer (score 0):

> Nothing is created even in the thumbnail folder. What should I do?

Check your paths. Save yourself some headache by actually using your `$config['upload_path']` definition.

You have:

```
$config['upload_path']  = './product_img';
```

Seems like it should have a trailing slash:

```
$config['upload_path']  = './product_img/';
```

You then go on to ignore `$config['upload_path']` altogether with literals, why I dunno.

You have, which has a logical error by the way, `$picname` is placed immediately after `./product_img` with no separating slash:

```
$config['source_image'] = './product_img'.$picname;
$config['new_image']    = './product_img/thumb';
```

I'm not following what you expect setting `new_image` set to the same value each time will do. It needs to be a different filename. Likely thats a `thumb` folder. If so you need to trail it with a slash, followed by `$picname`.

Consider revising your code so that you use your definition `$config['upload_path']`, like so:

```
            $config['upload_path']  = './product_img/';
            $config['allowed_types']    = 'gif|jpg|png'; 
            $config['overwrite']    = TRUE;
            $config['max_size'] = 10000000;
            $config['max_width']    = 10000;
            $config['max_height']   = 10000;
            $this->upload->initialize($config); 

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('pic13')) 
                $picname="";
            else
            {
                $picname=$this->upload->data("file_name");

                $config['image_library']    = 'gd2';
                $config['source_image'] = $config['upload_path'].$picname;
                $config['thumb_marker'] = '';
                $config['new_image']    = $config['upload_path'] . 'thumb/' . $picname;
                $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
                $config['maintain_ratio']   = TRUE;
                $config['width']    = 200;
                $config['height']   = 150;

                $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

                $this->image_lib->resize();
            }
            return $picname;
```

I'm not saying this all will magically solve all of your problems, but it will for these path discrepancies.